# Stacked bar chart with some negative values, one continuous stack

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know people have raised the issue of a stacked bar in d3 with negative values before, but I don't want to split the bars in two as the fix shows.

How can I keep it as one continuous stack?

Here is where I'm at: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/7f862b63e553de4273b2

Comment: how do you make a demo at `bl.ocks.org`??

Comment: you put the data and html into a github gist, publish and then edit the web address so that the beginning of it up until /anonymous... is as above.

Comment: @ozil [Let’s Make a Block](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/block/)